# How do I get data from an API which has data within {}?

Tags: javascript, json

How do I get the data from this?

```
body: {
    timestamp: 1611130470,
    metal: 'XAU',
    currency: 'GBP',
  }
```

Here is my code - I've tried doing body{} but that didn't work

```
const dat = JSON.stringify(res)
    const data = JSON.parse(dat)
    console.log(data.body) 
  result is undefined
```

And if I do this

```
const dat = JSON.stringify(res)
    const data = JSON.parse(dat)
    console.log(data.body.metal)
```

it says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'metal' of undefined
```

Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: did you check if `res` is already `stringify`d? Because that would explain why you don't need to "stringify" again.

Comment: the input is not valid JSON so it's unclear why you get that in the first place

Comment: Oh sorry, its because i shortened it because the returned json is really long. I would like to add that if i replace data.body.metal with data.text I get what I want, which is 

{"timestamp":1611130840,"metal":"XAU","currency":"GBP","exchange":"FOREXCOM","symbol":"FOREXCOM:XAUGBP","prev_close_price":1350.15,"open_price":1350.15,"low_price":1348.73,"high_price":1358.74,"open_time":1611093600,"price":1356.84,"ch":6.69,"chp":0.5,"ask":1357.16,"bid":1356.49}

So I'm just confused on how I get data from body{}

Comment: `if i replace data.body.metal with data.text` where `data.text` is likely a "string" and thus object notation returns "undefined". No, not a stupid question just lacking source code to be helped on. .... I dont understand these code lacking fragments for help